# How to properly work with Form Data params in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest, endpoint

I am doing a migration from Google Guice and JAX-RS to Spring Boot.
Prevously the method that I had looked like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/generateTable")
    public ExportResult generateTable(@FormParam("content") TableParam tableParam,
                                                      @FormParam("panel") PanelParam panelParam,
                                                      @FormParam("entityData") EntityDataParam entityDataParam,
                                                      @FormParam("drillPath") TypoParam typoParam)
```

Now I need to migrate this code in Spring Boot. I have looked at the request that is reaching this endpoint on Chrome DevTools and in the payload it has form data parameters.

When rewriting the code to Spring Boot, I realised that I cannot replace @FormParam with @RequestParam, so one solution that I have is to use this one:

```java
    @PostMapping("/generateTable")
    public ExportResult generateTable(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
```

But when using this approach I need to get the parameters from the formData hashmap and parse them to the appropriate object manually. Is there a way in which this can be done automatically without me checking whether an arguments has been passed and so for the other arguments.
Also another approach which I was thinking if it is possible to create a custom object containing all the params from the request and use @RequestBody to parse it automatically?

Any other approach would be of great help !

Comment: What is the error you get when you use `@RequestParam` that should be the replacement. Unless it cannot construct the object, you might need an additional `Converter` to convert the `String` into the object you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the JAX-RS request to Spring Boot MVC is straightforward with `@RequestParam` annotation. In your case something like this:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/generateTable", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ExportResult> generateTable(@RequestParam("content") TableParam tableParam,
                      @RequestParam("panel") PanelParam panelParam,
                      @RequestParam("entityData") EntityDataParam entityDataParam,
                      @RequestParam("drillPath") TypoParam typoParam))
```

Additionally you need to provide the converters from String to Java objects. You can identify the necessary code in the existing classes. It was either a constructor with a single String parameter or a static method named `valueOf()` or `fromString()` or a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider`.

Take this code and implement the `Converter<S, T>` interface in a Spring component. Similar to the example below. It constructs a Customer object from JSON String:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
@Component
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter<String, Customer> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public Customer convert(String customer) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(customer, Customer.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can limit content-type and use a object class to accept params.

On Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/form-data", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> generateTable(FormDataDTO data){

        return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
    }

}
```

FormDataDTO :

```
@Data
public class FormDataDTO {

     private TinyDTO tiny;

     private TinyDTO mid;

     private TinyDTO height;

}
```

TinyDTO :

```
@Data
public class TinyDTO {

    private String str;

    private Integer num;

}
```

How to request? You can test like this:

```
###
POST http://localhost:10001/test/form-data
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tiny.str"

aaaa
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tiny.num"

1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mid.str"

mid
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mid.num"

99
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="height.str"

height
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="height.num"

-1
--boundary--
```

Response is:

```
{
    "tiny": {
        "str": "aaaa",
        "num": 1
    },
    "mid": {
        "str": "mid",
        "num": 99
    },
    "height": {
        "str": "height",
        "num": -1
    }
}
```